# Add timestamp in a defined range upon clicking on CommandButton

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro which is to be used as a productivity tool. It timestamps a cell in a defined range, say, I8:I58 upon clicking CommandButton A. I8 gets timestamped. After clicking on CommandButton B, it timestamps I8Col+2. You get your time in production by subtracting the one from another.

When you click on CommandButton A the second time, I9 gets timestamped, and so on.

How do I do that? I'm having trouble defining a custom range.

I've tried using

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If IsEmpty(Range("I8")) Then
Range("I8").Value = Now
Else 
Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Now
```

But this won't work for me since column I contains data below the defined range of I8:I58. It would just timestamp cells way down the sheet.

I'm pretty sure there must be a very simple solution here

Comment: what does _"I8Col+2."_ mean?

Comment: and once you reach I58 where is next time stamp supposed to be written?

Comment: Same row, Column+2

Comment: There shouldn't be any timestamps in the same column after the limit is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close. Why don't you use this?

```
If IsEmpty(Range("I8")) Then
Range("I8").Value = Now
Else 
Range("I" & Range("I59").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Now 
'As the max row this can give is: I58. So nothing will ever be printed outside the range.
```

Comment: This solved the problem with custom range, but the first line makes it stuck at I9. If I8 is not empty, it timestamps I9, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If IsEmpty(Range("I8")) Then
        Range("I8").Value = Now
    Else
        With Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp) ' reference last not empty cell in column I
            If .Row < 58 Then .Offset(1).Value = Now ' if its is less then 57 then stamp on next row
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code I originally posted is faulty as I mentioned in the other comment. The     'If IsEmpty(Range("I8")) Then' conditional is lacking. What I need to do is to check every cell and timestamp the next empty cell, not just I8 or I9.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did try it, but it doesn't work, unfortunately. It only timestamps I8. Some of the cells out of the defined range are not empty. What I need is to get I9 timestamped, if I8 isn't empty, if I'm clicking on the commandbutton the second time. And to get I10 timestamped, if I8 and I9 are not empty. And I11, if I8, I9 and I10 are not empty. But this rule should only apply to I8:I58. There must be a better option than creating an if else rule for every single cell or creating 100 commandbuttons, right?

Comment: _"What I need is to get I9 timestamped, if I8 isn't empty, if I'm clicking on the commandbutton the second time. And to get I10 timestamped, if I8 and I9 are not empty. And I11, if I8, I9 and I10 are not empty. But this rule should only apply to I8:I58"_: that is precisely what the code is doing

Comment: I copied your code directly without making any changes whatsoever and it doesn't work. It only timestamps I8. It doesn't do anything when you click on the commandbutton the second time.

Comment: then cells I9 to I58 aren't empty

Comment: They are empty. But some of the cells below aren't. If i move everything else in the C column, your solution works fine, but it only works if Column C is empty outside the given range, which is not the case.